# Is it possible to run script or executable on Docker container with docker-compose.yml only without Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Scripts or executables can run on a *Docker container* automatically when running `docker-compose up --build` with a configured `Dockerfile` containing syntax `RUN`, through which a script or executables etc. can run automatically during build.

**Question: But is it possible to achieve the same goal, say run executables or scripts, with `docker-compose` only without a `Dockerfile`? In this case there are probably the similar command in `docker-compose.yml` like the `RUN` in `Dockerfile` ?**

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in docker-compose is overriding the default command that is executed after the build, by setting "command".

See here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

I don't think there is a RUN-like thing for docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the purpose of overriding the default command? Is there any real user case for this?

Comment: Yes, an example is adding a command when image does not provide one, or change flags to an existing image's command.

Comment: Thanks. But for instance, if the command is a shell script, we can also use Dockerfile with the COPY and RUN to do the same, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem, then the answer is yes: on your container configuration in your docker-compose.yml file use:

```
entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
command:
   - |
      ls -la
      echo 'hello'
```

or whatever is your commands you want to run.